# implementing onbackpressed in android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, onbackpressed

i have activity1 takes me to activity2 that takes me to fragment. i would like from fragment to go back to activity2

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: how can activity2 `take` you to a fragment ??? It can either open up a fragment in itself, or start another activity containing a fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding fragment from activity2 add it to backstack like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                           .replace(R.id.frame_layout, new SampleFragment())
                           .addToBackStack(SampleFragment.class.getSimpleName())
                           .commit();
```

And onBackPressed check if the fragment is present in backstack and pop it

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
        Fragment fragment=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.YOUR_FRAME_LAYOUT_ID);
        if(fragment!=null && fragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(SampleFragment.class.getSimpleName())){
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
        }
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

on fragments get the backpressed event and there call the

```
getactivity().getsupportfragmentmanager().popbackstack();
```

Answer (score -1):

Add that fragment transaction to backstack.